# Keep Java Thread running all the time

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, daemon, runnable

Looking for an elegant way to keep a Java thread running all the time in the background, as long as the application is running, for a JavaFX app checking to see is the User Credentials are valid or not. 
What I would be doing inside the `Thread` is expiring the users after certain interval

Comment: Why would you need to do this? Surely this would only change if the user changed something (e.g. provided a username or a password). Why not only check when that happened?

Comment: Need to expire User credentials after certain interval for a JavaFX application

Comment: Can you update the question with that information? Also other pertinent information, such as when (under what conditions) you would want to reset the timeout?

Comment: Why not just reject queries after a timeout period? @james_d is right, there's no need for a background thread here.

Comment: @DonBranson Need to null out the Credentials object after certain interval so that users are forced to login

Comment: I didn't think you do. When a request comes in after the timeout, you just force a login.

Comment: @DonBranson If you want the UI to be reactive, you probably need some kind of timing mechanism. It's not a good UX for the user to fill out a form and submit it, only then to be told their session has expired. You want that feedback immediately in the UI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to timeout the login you can use a `PauseTransition` to expire the login:

```
Duration timeout = Duration.minutes(...);
PauseTransition logoutTimer = new PauseTransition(timeout);
logoutTimer.setOnFinished(e -> expireCredentials());
logoutTimer.play();
```

If you need to reset the timeout at any point, you can just do

```
logoutTimer.playFromStart();
```

and it will reset the timer.

You can also use JavaFX properties to make this easy to manage in the application. E.g.

```
private BooleanProperty loggedIn = new SimpleBooleanProperty();

// ...

public void expireCredentials() {
    loggedIn.set(false);
}
```

Then operations which require the user to be logged in can check this property:

```
if (loggedIn.get()) {
    doSecureOperation();
}
```

and UI controls can bind their states to it:

```
submitSecureDataButton.disableProperty().bind(loggedIn.not());
loginButton.disableProperty().bind(loggedIn);
```

or perhaps

```
private ObjectProperty<Credentials> credentials = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

// ...

public void expireCredentials() {
    credentials.set(null);
}

// ...

submitSecureDataButton.disableProperty().bind(credentials.isNull());
loginButton.disableProperty().bind(credentials.isNotNull());
```

Comment: Curious to know how would PauseTransition compare against the Timeline approach

Comment: @JohnC Basically no difference: `PauseTransition` is more convenient when it does what you need. If you want a repeating action, or want to do things at multiple time points, you need a timeline. Both work the same way. (No threading involved.)

Comment: Yes in fact I need this to happen all the time as long as the application is running. So looks like Timeline is more suitable for my use-case then

Comment: @JohnC Wouldn't you just restart the timer when the user logged back in though? Not immediately when the user was automatically logged out?

Comment: Credentials store the userLoggedInTime and gets populated when the user logs in. After certain interval for all the machines, I need to null out the Credentials thereby forcing users to re-login. The timer needs to be restarted when the user logs in

Comment: @JohnC Right, but a timeline with `cycleCount` set to `INDEFINITE` would null out the credentials every `x` seconds. You want to null out the credentials `x` seconds *after they log in*. (Imagine the user is away from the machine, after `x` seconds the credentials are nulled out. They happen to return and complete their new login `x-1` seconds after that... they would be logged out again 1 second later.) So you just create a single `PauseTransition` and call `playFromStart()` on it when the user logs in.

Comment: Awesome @James_D